# Spicing up the Visual Studio IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Currently I have ReSharper installed to help me develop and edit code, and made a good layout for my Visual Studio (2008) over two screens. I have changed the settings of the text windows (mainly the output Window on the right) to have a black background and smaller text.

I tried SlickEdit gadgets yesterday, but it doesn't perform very well in my opinion.

What other addins or trick do you use to further customize or enhance your Visual Studio experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What Visual Studio Add Ins Do You Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784/what-visual-studio-add-ins-do-you-use)

[What Is Your favorite Visual Studio Add In / Setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106340/what-is-your-favorite-visual-studio-add-in-setting)

[Customizing Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908/customizing-visual-studio)

[Do You Have Any Recommended Add Ons / Plugins for Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767/do-you-have-any-recommended-add-ons-plugins-for-microsoft-visual-studio)

Answer (score 4):

[Whole Tomato's Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

I'm not sure I could live without it...

Answer (score 2):

PowerCommands is a MUST have

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=559