# Looking for variable hightlight feature in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I had been looking for a "variable highlight" feature which can be found in Netbeans or Notepad++.

This means, when I select a variable, the same variable which is being scattered around other place will be highlighted as well. This feature is very valuable, to help me scan the code quickly.

May I know is it possible I can have this feature as well in Visual Studio 2008?

[image]

Comment: doesn't resharper do something like this?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494/visual-studio-identical-token-highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) and you will be able many useful features. This particular one is called **highlight usage** and is available when pressing Ctrl + Shift + F7. The description is at:

- http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Highlight_Usages

Comment: I still need to press the keystroke? In Notepad++, the feature is completely automatic.

Comment: Yes, you do have to press that combination.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 this feature is build-in.