# Visual Studio 2012 identical token highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Connected with [Visual Studio identical token highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494/visual-studio-identical-token-highlighting) but need this functionality for VS2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works in VS 2013 with Productivity Power Tools 2013

Answer (score 1):

For C#: Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors => Highlight Reference.