# Variable background colors for different scopes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting, scope

I was wondering if there was any sort of add-in or feature with VS (2008 preferably) for vb.net / c# that would highlight variables differently based on their scope, i.e. method scope, inner scope (i.e. inside if...else), class scope, global scope, so on and so forth.

It looks like ReSharper might have this functionality, but free software would be preferable.  If you think ReSharper is great though, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I use to use "this" for globals, but different colors by variable scope would be nice. Have you found the plugin?

Comment: Visual Assist X was the closest I found--it only has special highlighting for method local variables, though.  It'd still be nice to have visual signifiers for out-of-class variables.  It has a free trial and looks fairly affordable if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.h.,

Maybe you can see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494/visual-studio-identical-token-highlighting) and i think you will find what you want

Comment: That seems to only deal with per-variable highlighting.  I'm talking about, for example, light orange text background for all variables defined in methods, light green background for variables defined in classes, and light blue background for variables defined globally.

Comment: Well i think that if you want free software to do that you would upgrade your visual studio to vs 2010 and take the productivity power tools that could do what you want

Comment: Visual Assist X was the closest I found